# Chrome (on VirtualBox) shows blank pages

Tags: virtualbox, google-chrome

I've just installed google Chrome in Ubuntu (on VM) but it doesn't show web pages correctly. I tried to reinstall it - didn't help. Pic is provided.[chrome doesn't show web pages correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duW7Y.jpg)

Has anybody had such issues? If you can help, please, be sure to provide step-by-step guide how to fix that since I've been using it for a couple of hours and don't know how all things work here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome.

Comment: How much Video RAM have you allowed your VM in Virtual box?

Comment: As much as I could. 128 if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't already, it's a good idea to maximize the Video RAM available to the VM in Virtualbox as a shortage can cause some rather odd video anomalies.

Having done that follow up by opening chrome://settings/ and going to Advanced.

uncheck the related box (2nd below system) shown checked below.[image: accel]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I cannot see the panel/buttons so there's no way I can get in settings

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue with Chrome, nothing was showing up correctly anymore. I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with VirtualBox 5.1.8 and I am pretty sure this issue first appeared right after installing OpenJDK 8.

This issue was solved for me by disabling hardware acceleration as @ElderGeek said in his answer, but to get there you have to:

1. Shutdown the virtual machine (VM)
2. For that VM in VirtualBox, go to Settings -> Display and uncheck 'Enable 3D Acceleration'
3. Start the VM again and start Chrome, everything should be displayed correctly at this point
4. In Chrome, go to Settings -> click 'Show advanced settings', scroll down to 'Use hardware acceleration when available' and uncheck it as shown by @ElderGeek
5. Finally, shutdown the VM again and reactivate 3D acceleration in the VMs settings

It was just an intuitive guess, but it worked for me.